# Convert cell address as string to cell range

Tags: excel, vba, button, cell

I have a cell J9 whose value is the address of other random cells, for example "$CW$178". I want then to add a shape in a cell whose address is the same as J9.Value, so in this case I would've added a circle in the $CW$178 cell. However, everytime I execute my macro I get returned Run-time error '424': Object required.

This is my code:

```
Sub button0_Click()
Cell2 = Range("J9").Value
Set shpOval = Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, Cell2.Left, Cell2.Top, 50, 50) <--Debug highlights this line
```

Comment: `Set Cell2 = Range(Range("J9").Value)`. Also needs `ActiveSheet.` in front of `Shapes`.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, but I get the same error. And I actually want to put the shape in another sheet, but I didn't add that part for the sake of complexity.
```Set visualizer = Sheets("Visualizer")
    Set Cell2 = Range(Range("J9").Value)
    Set shpOval = visualizer.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, Cell2.Left, Cell2.Top, 50, 50)
End Sub```

@EDIT
Actually, no error happens after I press End, but the shape is created in a different cell for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range`s need `Set`. Also you are missing a worksheet reference before `Shapes`.

```
Dim visualizer As Worksheet
Set visualizer = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Visualizer") ' or ThisWorkbook.

Dim Cell2 As Range
Set Cell2 = visualizer.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J9").Value)

Dim shpOval As Shape
Set shpOval = visualizer.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, Cell2.Left, Cell2.Top, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to add the shape to another worksheet.

I've added your changes, however it seems to add the shape in a random cell. This is my full code:

`
Sub button0_Click()
    Set visualizer = Sheets("Visualizer")
    Dim Cell2 As Range
    Set Cell2 = Range(Range("J9").Value)

    Dim shpOval As Shape
    Set shpOval = visualizer.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, Cell2.Left, Cell2.Top, 50, 50)
    Range("E9").Value = Range("J10").Value <-- Irrelevant
    Range("F9").Value = Range("J11").Value <-- Irrelevant
End Sub
`

Comment: What is the "random cell" it adds the shape in?

Comment: The shapes spread all over the sheet, sometimes going to cells as far as ADP146.

Comment: Try `Set Cell2 = visualizer.Range(Range("J9").Value)`.